# RealityKit iOS Metal Shader rendering colors incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, metal, realitykit

So I'm using Metal to write custom shaders for my entities in RealityKit so that I can create gradients, but the colors are rendering strangely once I apply the gradient. The color renders correctly at full RGB values, e.g. (1,0,0), (1,1,1), (1,1,0), etc. but when using decimal values the render is incorrect. Here's a screenshot showing the values. The squares in front have simple single color shaders applied and the ones in the back are colored with a UIColor on the Material in RealityKit. In all of these, I'm using UnlitMaterial and the base MeshResource.generatePlane() function.

[image]

These are the color values used as UIColors in the back, and as Metal half3s in the front.

```
let color1 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
let color2 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1)
let color3 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
let color4 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1)
let color5 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.875, blue: 0.875, alpha: 1)
let color6 = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

Here's one of the Metal Shaders

```
[[visible]]
void colorShader2(realitykit::surface_parameters params) {
    // Gets surface parameters
    auto surface = params.surface();
    
    half value = 0.25;
    
    // set color to RGB Values
    half3 color = half3(1,value,value);
    
    // Set the base color to the color
    surface.set_emissive_color(color);
    surface.set_base_color(color);
    
    surface.set_opacity(half(1.0));
}
```

Here's the Swift code to apply the shader, largely pulled from Apple's documentation. These functions are in an extension of the Entity type.

```
func loadCustomSurfaceShader(mySurfaceShader: String) -> CustomMaterial.SurfaceShader {

        // Get the Metal Device.
        guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
            fatalError("Error creating default metal device.")
        }

        // Get a reference to the Metal library.
        guard let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary() else {
            fatalError("Error creating default Metal library")
        }
        
        // Load a surface shader function named mySurfaceShader.
        let surfaceShader = CustomMaterial.SurfaceShader(named: mySurfaceShader,
                                                         in: library)
        
        return surfaceShader
    }
    
    func replaceMaterialWithCustomMaterial(entity: Entity, surfaceShader: CustomMaterial.SurfaceShader) {

        // Make sure the entity has a ModelComponent.
        guard var modelComponent = entity.components[ModelComponent.self] as? ModelComponent else {
            return
        }

        // Loop through the entity's materials and replace the existing material with
        // one based on the original material.
        guard let customMaterials = try? modelComponent.materials.map({ material -> CustomMaterial in
            let customMaterial = try CustomMaterial(from: material, surfaceShader: surfaceShader)
            return customMaterial
        }) else { return}
        modelComponent.materials = customMaterials
        entity.components[ModelComponent.self] = modelComponent
    }
    
    func applyShader(_ shader: LookShaders) {
        let shader = self.loadCustomSurfaceShader(mySurfaceShader: shader.rawValue)
        self.replaceMaterialWithCustomMaterial(entity: self, surfaceShader: shader)
    }
```

I'm pretty stumped as to why this is happening, but I'm sure there might be something simple enough I'm missing.

Comment: I feel like this has to do with sRGB conversions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth.

Comment: MTLPixelFormat conversion. I had this issue just today. I forgot to set a proper color format and was going between ABGR and RGBA, and there are MANY. Metal needs to know the color format (setting MTLPixelFormat on the texture), or you need to pass the color in as RGBAu8norm (and interpreted as half4 in metal, not half3) to use Metal's default setting.

Comment: @Dev4Hire Thanks for the info. Where would I pass this info in? Do I just set that in the shader itself? I haven't found a way to pass data to Metal shaders through RealityKit, which would be really helpful for other uses as well. I'm not well versed in all the different color formats or Metal, I just want the Metal shader colors to match the UIColors. Thanks!

Comment: If the format expected is BGRA instead of RGBA (for instance) then change `half3(1,value,value);` to `half3(value,value,1);`

Comment: @Jake you would pass the MTLPixelFormat into either your MTLTextureDescriptor (before you create a texture) or your fragment shader (if you're coloring vertices). Unfortunately I haven't used RealityKit, I was using just Metal for weather applications, but check all of the settings around the fragment shader and textures and see if you can find anything related to PixelFormat or ColorSpace or ColorFormat.

Comment: Yeah, so the above code is all there is regarding metal in my app, so I never used MTLPixelFormat or MTLTextureDescriptor. I've just ignored the problem for now...